# Connecting Database from lift app using mapper error

Tags: mysql, database, scala, lift, mapper

I am trying to connect my lift app to the database. i have the following code to do the operation. i have downloaded and included the lift-mapper_2.9.1 to my app and i have given the following code in boot.scala

```
import net.liftweb.mapper.{DB,Schemifier,DefaultConnectionIdentifier,StandardDBVendor,MapperRules}

class boot{
  def boot{
    ......
    .......
   }
      object Database extends StandardDBVendor(
    Props.get("db.class").openOr("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"),
    Props.get("db.url").openOr("jdbc:mysql://localhost/scalatest"),
    Props.get("db.user"),
    Props.get("db.pass"))
 }
```

i have setup the db.class and other properties in src/main/resources/props/default.props file.
but here one error is showing in the first line that,

```
  Multiple markers at this line
- bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to term db in package net.liftweb which is not available. It may be completely 
 missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.
- too many arguments for constructor Object: ()Object
```

i don't know what i did wrong. can anydoby give a suggestion. thanx in advance.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question asked, but try to start from a simple app and add changes one by another: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/
For example, the main way to use a StandardDBVendor is by creating it with a "new" keyword rather than extending it as an object:
https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/blob/master/scala_29/lift_basic/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala

Comment: The same simple app i'm downloaded and trying to do changes. in that i faced this problem.

Comment: I did the same which you provided in the second link. but still the same error is showing.

Comment: Is it a compilation error? What's it's text, exactly? We need more info to be able to help...

Comment: yes. its a compilation error. the text i mentioned above in the question starting with multiple markers at this line. (i'm using eclipse IDE)